# Fuseki 2: Security issue "Information Exposure"

Tags: jetty-9, fuseki

I'm working with Apache Fuseki 2.3.1. on Linux RedHat as a standalone server:

```
>> java -Xmx16384M -jar fuseki-server.jar --port=8080 --loc=/space/tdb /ds
```

The safety tests team has raised an anomaly of "Information Exposure" (CWE-200 - http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/200.html), in particular the Fuseki and JETTY versions are showed.
For example, if I submit an incorrect query, it's shown:

```
Error 400: ...
Fuseki - version 2.3.1 ....
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by Jena/Fuseki team and will be released on next version of Fuseki (2.4.0).
See:
[Suppress output of "Server:" with version information.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1125)

Comment: You should include any relevant information from that link as part of your answer so that it is still available in event that the link is dead. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer